# Symfony how to switch environment without logging out the user

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony you can change environment in your front controller, e.g. from `prod` to `dev`:

```
if (/* some conditions */) {
    $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
} else {
    $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
}

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

but every time that the environment changes, the user is being logged out. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: why would you need this?

Comment: because it's annoying to log out and log in again each time you change environment, it would be more much handy not to have to do it

Comment: I suspect that when you switch environments, you lose your session bag, where the logged in user data is stored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session data is by default kept in `/var/sessions/<env name>`, which means that for dev and prod environments you simply have separate sessions.

You could change that in configuration under `framework:sessione:save_path`.
By default in `config.yml` it looks like:

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
```

You can change it to be always the same directory by changing `%kernel.environment%` into something static.

Alternatively you could override dev config in`config_dev.yml` to use prod sessions by putting such configuration in that file:

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/prod"
```